# How can I pass an generic Collection even if collection type is not satisfying the requirements?

Tags: java, generics

I have a conventional method to pass a collection as argument that would have to have a type either to be same or superclass of Vehicle class. Also I have two subclass which are Van and Truck.

```java
private static void changeLength(Collection<? super Vehicle> collection) {
    //
}
```

But when I invoke this method like below I don't have any problem. Even if my collection is of type Vehicle, members of this collection is actually pointing to subclass types (Van,Truck).

```java
public static void testCaseTwo() {
    List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
    vehicles.add(new Van(12));
    vehicles.add(new Truck(12));
    // No runtime error here. but first member of this collection is
    // referencing to Van class
    // How am I still able to pass this collection as an argument?
    changeLength(vehicles);
```

Do I have a big misunderstanding here?

Comment: vehicles is a list of ```Vehicle```, why it shouldn't work?

Comment: What objects in the list refers to doesn't matter. Only the type of `vehicles` - `List<Vehicle>` - matters when type checking this.

Comment: This makes sense. Even if I pass Vehicle typed List , members of this list was subtypes of vehicle and it has been making me confused. But from type checking point of view , I can accept that.